# jasperexception request cannot be resolved

Tags: jsp

I have two files:

ShortCatalog.jsp:

```
<form method="POST" action="ShortWroxShopController.jsp">
    <input type="submit" value="Add to cart" name="AddToCartButton" />
    <input type="hidden" value="1861004958" name="ISBN" />
    <input type="hidden" value="AddToCart" name="Action" />
</form>
```

ShortWroxShopController.jsp:

```
<%  String action = request.getParameter("Action");
    String ISBN   = reguest.getParameter("ISBN");
%>

<%=action %>
```

When I click on button "Add to cart" I get :

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 3 in the jsp file: /ShortWroxShopController.jsp
reguest cannot be resolved
1: 
2: <%  String action = request.getParameter("Action");
3:     String ISBN   = reguest.getParameter("ISBN");
4: %>
5: 
6: <%=action %>
```

Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `request` with a `q`, not `g`. Exactly the same as you successfully used in the line there above.

[image]

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, you should prefer [Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) over JSP as controller.

Comment: Oh my, I fell so dumb. Thank you.
Servlet? Yes, I am getting there. I am studying 
Beginning JSP web development (http://javaboutique.internet.com/resources/books/BeginJSPWebDev/)